# Variable in filename\path in windows command line

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line

**EDIT**: Added actual data

I need to write a simple *.bat file that would copy files from a predifined set of folders somehwere else
So I need something like this:

```
FOR %%i IN (ADH452, ADH457, ADH459) DO (

copy C:\MyFOLDERS\%%i_DATA\file.ext C:\DESTINATION\

)
```

The problem is I cannot find the correct syntaxis for using %i in a path\filename.

Comment: What you have shown us *should* work - there must be something about the *actual* values you are using that prevents it, if it's not working. Please post *actual* data to obviate speculation.

Comment: If you're copying `file.ext` from three locations to a single specified location, each will be overwritten by the last, meaning you'll only have one `file.txt` in `C:\DESTINATION`. Is that your issue, because otherwise there's nothing wrong with your code!

Answer (score 0):

To avoid overwriting the file in destination you could prepend the folder name to the filename

```
FOR %%i IN (ADH452, ADH457, ADH459) DO (
    copy "C:\MyFOLDERS\%%i_DATA\file.ext" "C:\DESTINATION\%%i_file.ext"
)
```